# convert time using mysql laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to view the time which store on DB 12:00:00 as 12:00 PM.

here is my code

```
$late_running = Late_runnings::select(DATE_FORMAT('late_time','%h:%i %p'))
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                    ->where('role_id', '=', 1)
                    ->get();
```

im getting follwing error

```
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

pls advice

Comment: Are you following? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: what you get for `dd($late_running);`

Comment: @K.Toress :         "week_id" => 3
        "late_date" => "2015-12-10"
        "late_time" => "03:00:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT` is a mysql property so you need to select it as a raw sql like,

```
Late_runnings::selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT('late_time','%h:%i %p')")...
```

didn't test it give it a try. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$late_running = Late_runnings::select("DATE_FORMAT(late_time,'%h:%i %p')")
                ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                ->where('role_id', '=', 1)
                ->get();
```